# Why do we get a connected 2-regular graph?

Tags: graph-theory, elliptic-curves, cryptography

In reading "[PUBLIC-KEY CRYPTOSYSTEM BASED ON ISOGENIES](https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/145.pdf)" by Rostovtsev and Stolbunov, they claim on page 8 that the set $U=\{E_i(\mathbb{F}_p)\}$ of elliptic curves with a specific prime $l$ form a "branchless cycle".

For some context,

- $U$ is a set of elliptic curves, each one being a uniquely determined by a $j$-invariant.
- $l$ is a prime such that the Kronecker symbol $\left(\frac{D_\pi}{l}\right)=1$, and $D_\pi$ is the Frobenius discriminant (which is common among all the elliptic curves in $U$ because they are all isogenous by Tate's theorem).

Kohel (Theorem 2 in paper) showed that if an elliptic curve has $D_\pi$ and $l$ satisfying $\left(\frac{D_\pi}{l}\right)=1$, then there are exactly two $l$-degree isogenies from $E$.

Now this implies $U$ is $2$-regular, but why does the following statement hold:

> It is practically determined that, when $\#U$ is prime, all the elements of $U$ form a single isogeny cycle.

If $\#U=7$ can't we have two disjoint cycles of size $3$ and $4$? And why must $\#U$ be prime?

Cross-post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/467175/why-do-we-get-a-connected-2-regular-graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered on MO (MathOverflow)
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/467175/why-do-we-get-a-connected-2-regular-graph/467743#467743.

The construction makes $U$ the Cayley graph associated to an abelian group $G$
and a pair $\pm g$ of elements of $G$. In such a graph all the components
are cycles of the same length, namely the order of $g$, call it $|g|$.
Thus $|g|$ is a factor of $|G|$ (this is also part of Lagrange's theorem).
In particular if $|G|$ is prime and $g$ is not the identity element then
$|g| = |G|$ and the graph is a single $|G|$-cycle.

See the MO answer for further information.